# Writing input to c executable manually trigger exploit, but python input does not

Tags: python, c

I have this little exploitable file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// gcc -z execstack -z norelro -fno-stack-protector -o format0 format0.c
int target;

void vuln(char *string)
{
    printf(string);
    if (target){
        printf("Tyes yes eys");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    vuln(argv[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

It's very simple, I compile like this:

```
gcc file.c -o file -no-pie
```

and then I run it like this get it to leak some values:

```
./file %x
38b3fda8
```

Which works prefectly.
But I want to automate this a bit, using python. So I try the following:

```
$ ./form &(python -c "print('%x'*3)")
[1] 30633
%x%x%x
[1]+  Done                    ./form
```

and this looks super weird. Firstly, the string format error is not triggered.  Then it prints it's own name and some other random stuff.
I also tried doing this in gdb, with the same result.

How do I give input with python like every other tutorial online?

Comment: Why would you write a Python program for this at all? `./form $(python -c "print('%x'*3)")` is exactly the same as `./form %x%x%x`, except harder to read, slower to run, and more error-prone.

Comment: Note also that this isn't providing **input** from Python; it's providing **command line arguments** from Python. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
./form $(python -c "print('%x'*3)")
```

What `./form &(python -c "print('%x'*3)")`
does is:

```
/form &
(python -c "print('%x'*3)")
```

i.e. form is run in the background. (Process 30633) in your example.
Python is run in the foreground in a subshell. (And prints out %x%x%x to your terminal)